# Ember-data 1.0 Beta 2 Issue with transition after save for the first time

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am creating a sample application using ember 1.0 and ember-data 1.0 Beta 2.0. with RESTAdapter to connect to backend server. 
   When I try to save a record, it always invoke failure handler at the first submission. But the record actually gets saved at backend without fail. From the server the response for submission contains the created entity set with id. 
   When I try to debug the code in developer tools, it actually goes through the code for route transition, but then it returns back to Add view before completing the transition. It seems to be some callbacks from jQuery global event handlers are causing the problem.

Here is the code I am using

```
App.AddResourceRoute = App.ResourceManagerRoute.extend(
{
    model: function () {
        return this.store.createRecord('Resource');
    },
    actions: {
        save: function () {
            this.modelFor('AddResource').save().then(function (resource) {
                App.Router.router.transitionToRoute('Resources');
            }, function (reason) {
                alert('Failure reason:' + reason);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Please help me to find out what is wrong with my code.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are receiving an error from `App.Router.router.transitionToRoute('Resources');` invocation, try to update to the following:

```
App.AddResourceRoute = App.ResourceManagerRoute.extend(
{
    model: function () {
        return this.store.createRecord('Resource');
    },
    actions: {
        save: function () {
            var route = this;
            this.modelFor('AddResource').save().then(function (resource) {
                route.transitionTo('Resources');
            }, function (reason) {
                alert('Failure reason:' + reason);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

You should use `transitionTo(someRoute)` inside of a route, or `transitionToRoute(someRoute)` when inside of a controller

Comment: Thanks for your help. But unfortunately this does not seem to be the reason. I updated the code as above, but still getting the error. The record gets saved to server, but the code for route transition does not get invoked. When I check network tab in developer tools, it shows as the ajax request cancelled.